# SQL where clause for two no relationship tables that match some criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, where-clause

I have two tables:

Sales

```
+----+--------------+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| id |  date        |     type      |   city    |   value    |     GB     |
+----+--------------+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 1  |  2014-12-20  |     type1     |   city1   |    1000    |    100     |            
+----+--------------+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 2  |  2014-12-20  |     type2     |   city2   |    2000    |    200     |   
+----+--------------+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 3  |  2014-12-20  |     type2     |   city1   |    3000    |    300     |
+----+--------------+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 4  |  2014-12-19  |     type1     |   city1   |    4000    |    400     |       
+----+--------------+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Notes

```
+----+--------------+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| id |  date        |     type      |   city    |   value    |     GB     |
+----+--------------+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 1  |  2014-12-20  |     type1     |   city1   |    100     |     10     |            
+----+--------------+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 2  |  2014-12-19  |     type2     |   city2   |    200     |     20     |   
+----+--------------+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 3  |  2014-12-20  |     type1     |   city1   |    300     |     30     |
+----+--------------+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+

DECLARE @date DATE
SET @date = '2014-12-20'
```

I need to subtract the sum() of `value` and `GB` columns of both tables, and show the result grouped by type and city

```
select sales.type, sales.city, sum(sales.value) - sum(notes.value) as raw_value_sales, sum(sales.GB)-sum(notes.GB) as raw_GB_sales from sales,notes
where notes.date = @date and sales.date = @date
group by sales.type, sales.city
```

This query doesn't work because it crosses the tables.

Required output

```
+---------- --------+---------------+--------------------+----------------+
|    sales_type     |  sales_city   |  raw_value_sales   |  raw_GB_sales  | 
+-------------------+---------------+--------------------+----------------+
|      type1        |    city1      |        600         |      60        |                
+-------------------+---------------+--------------------+----------------+
|      type2        |    city1      |        3000        |      300       |
+-------------------+---------------+--------------------+----------------+
|      type2        |    city2      |        2000        |      200       |
+-------------------+---------------+--------------------+----------------+
```

Note that these data is just to get my problem be explained. For type2 there isn't notes in the @date required so the raw_values_sales and raw_GB_sales keep the same.

I was trying with this sql statement to test the where clause:

```
select notes.date, sales.date
from Notes, Sales
WHERE notes.date = @date and ventas.date = @date
```

It shows 20994 recors however as mentioned I know there are 476 sales that match that criteria  and  44 notes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: How can I select records for sales and notes applying the where conditions for both?

Comment: This shouldn't be the case. I guess that the problem is the way you are joining both tables

Comment: You will probably get a useful answer if you show the SQL instead of just describing it.  No way to help here with a description of what you are doing.

Comment: Using an AND condition in your WHERE predicate maybe?

Comment: where Sales.date = @Date and Notes.date = _Date (I hope your real columns have better names)

Comment: Do you mean that it shows **20944** records, rather than 20994? Because that would be consistent with one table having 476 rows and the other having 44 rows, and you essentially implementing a CROSS JOIN with your SQL.

Comment: is there a way to get just real records that match that criteria for both tables. Do i have to use multiple selects?

Comment: @alejandrozuleta That would be sensible if there's absolutely zero relationship between the two sets of data.

Comment: Is there a salesId column on the notes table?

Comment: No, there isn't a fk in notes. As i mentioned in the title the tables have not relationship. Even if would be a fk i think it is useless in this case because i just need the records that match the criteria for both tables not related ones.

Comment: You said the tables were not related but it appears they *are* related – through `type` and `city`.

Comment: The tables aren't related by a key (fk) as I said in my latest comment above yours. I don't know how can set a relation by type or city that can help in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have edited your question it is maybe a little clearer what you are after. I think you are going to need to use sub-queries to achieve the result you want. I'm not sure how efficient it is, but I think this test script demonstrates a possible technique:

```
create table sales (
    id int primary key,
    [date] date,
    [type] varchar(max),
    city varchar(max),
    value int,
    GB int);

insert into sales
    (id, [date], [type], city, value, GB)
values
    (1, '2014-12-20', 'type1', 'city1', 1000, 100),            
    (2, '2014-12-20', 'type2', 'city2', 2000, 200),   
    (3, '2014-12-20', 'type2', 'city1', 3000, 300),
    (4, '2014-12-19', 'type1', 'city1', 4000, 400);

create table notes
    (id int primary key,
    [date] date,
    [type] varchar(max),
    city varchar(max),
    value int,
    GB int);

insert into notes
    (id, [date], [type], city, value, GB)
values
    (1, '2014-12-20', 'type1', 'city1', 100, 10),
    (2, '2014-12-19', 'type2', 'city2', 200, 20),
    (3, '2014-12-20', 'type1', 'city1', 300, 30);

declare
    @date date = '2014-12-20';

select
    [type], 
    [city],
    sum(value) - isnull((select sum(value) from notes n where n.date=@date and n.[type] = s.[type] and n.city = s.city),0) raw_value_sales,
    sum(GB) - isnull((select sum(GB) from notes n where n.date=@date and n.[type] = s.[type] and n.city = s.city),0) raw_GB_sales
from
    sales s
where
    [date]=@date
group by 
    [type], 
    [city]
;

drop table notes;
drop table sales;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I never could figure out this way. I was thinking my problem was SRSS Querysets editor but it allows use nested selects. Thanks again